# how to solve shift-reduce conflict in yacc

Tags: yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I wrote the c-minor compiler with `yacc` and it now says it has 2 shift-reduce conflict and it shows these 2 lines:

> line has var '-='
>         line has var '+='

```
expression : var '=' expression 
            |var '+=' expression
            |var '−=' expression
            |simple_expression
            ;
var :ID
    |ID '[' expression ']'
    ;
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: General answer for conflicts: run yacc (or bison) with the -v flag to produce a y.output file and look at that to see where the conflicts are coming from